# a href link not clickable on safari mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, hyperlink, timeline

I'm in the process of testing for cross-browser compatibility on a timeline I've created here: http://bmcmahen.com/timeline/timeline.html

I'm trying to use highslide so that when I click on an entry in the timeline, it opens up a new window containing more information. This works well in every browser except Safari Mobile. With Safari mobile even regular  links are not even clickable in the div. This suggests to me that it (a) isn't a javascript error (which is reinforced by the safari mobile debugger which doesn't report any errors), and (b) that it's something to do with css, or the way in which safari (mobile only) handles touch events.

Code as it's displayed:

```
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 350px; left: 92.48811740233592px; " class="timeline-event timeline-event-box">
    <div class="timeline-event-content">
     <div style="">
       <a href="fallback.html" title="Testing a link in mobile Safari." onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this)">
        <p class="name">I should open a highslide window</p>
    </a>
    <p class="date"><a href="http://www.google.com">Regular Link</a></p>
    <div class="highslide-maincontent">
        This is the main content. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this sample node on the left hand side, near 1860. The CSS is available through web inspector or firebug.

UPDATE: I might be wrong about the problem being the CSS. I disabled the touch event handlers that come with the timeline.js api, and while pinching and scrolling no longer work with swipes, the links now work.